# Looking for ideal method to "scrub" csv file to be put into Excel

Tags: python, csv, slice

Bit of an involved setup to this question, but bear with me!

(Copy and pasting the below block into an editor works well)

I am using clevercsv to load my data from a financial website's csv file.
Each row is stored as an item in a list.

`data = clevercsv.wrappers.read_csv(in_file_name)`

After some account info lines, the stock data begins:

`stock_data = data[8:]`

I wish to remove the data: Market, Loan Value - all the way to - Day High (inclusive0

And Keep Symbol, Description -> % of Positions (inclusive), 52-wk Low, 52-wk High

Each stock has this data associated with it on the relevant line.
Any best practices for removing this data? I have been trying and seem to be having logic errors.

> As of Date,2020-04-29 18:44:29
>
> Account,TD Direct Investing - HAHAHA
>
> Cash,123.12
>
> Investments,1234.12
>
> Total Value,12345.12
>
> Margin,123456.12,
>
> ,
>
> Symbol,Market,Description,Quantity,Average Cost,Price,Book Cost,Market Value,Unrealized $,Unrealized %,% of Positions,Loan Value,Change Today $,Change Today %,Bid,Bid Lots,Ask,Ask Lots,Volume,Day Low,Day High,52-wk Low,52-wk High
>
> AFL,US,"AFLAC INC",500,43.79,39.23,21895.79,19615.00,-2280.79,-10.42,7.26,,1.4399986,3.81,39.19,1,40.2,1,3001288,38.31,39.48,23.07,57.18
>
> AKTS,US,"AKOUSTIS TECHNOLOGIES INC",2500,5.04,8.94,12609.87,22350.00,9740.13,77.24,8.27,,0.35999966,4.20,8.68,1,9.2,10,1161566,8.65,9.25,3.76,9.25

And here is my code so far:

```
import clevercsv
data = clevercsv.wrappers.read_csv(in_file_name)

# store the earlier lines for later use, all rows 8 and later are stock data
cash = data[2]
investments = data[3]
tot_value = data[4]
margin = data[5]
full_header = data[7]
stock_data = data[8:]

new_header = []
new_stock_data = []

# I have found the index positions I wish to save, append their data to the new_ lists:
for i in range(len(full_header)):
    if i == 0:
        new_header.append(full_header[i])
    if (i >= 2 and i <= 10):
        new_header.append(full_header[i])
    if i == 21:
        new_header.append(full_header[i])
    if i == 22: 
        new_header.append(full_header[i])
# I have found the index positions I wish to save, append their data to the new_ lists:
for i in range(len(stock_data)):
    if i == 0:
        new_stock_data.append(stock_data[i])
    if (i >= 2 and i <= 10):
        new_stock_data.append(stock_data[i])
    if i == 21:
        new_stock_data.append(stock_data[i])
    if i == 22: 
        new_stock_data.append(stock_data[i])

with open(os.path.join(folder_path,out_file_name),'w') as out_file:
    writer = clevercsv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerow(cash)
    writer.writerow(investments)
    writer.writerow(tot_value)
    writer.writerow(margin)
    writer.writerow(new_header)
    for row in new_stock_data:
         writer.writerow(row)
```

If this is too involved I understand, and if someone has a better library to use, or a better way to use the csv library that will be plenty of help on it's own.

Comment: This looks a job for Pandas:  https://pandas.pydata.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the column indices and the header length, you can do something like this:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'r', newline='') as input_file, open('output.csv','w', newline='') as output_file:
    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
    writer = csv.writer(output_file)

    for line_number, row in enumerate(reader, start=0):  # Avoid range(len(x))
        if line_number < 7:
            writer.writerow(row)  # Write cash, investments, etc
        else:
            shortened_row = row[0:1] + row[2:11] + row[21:] # Slice only the columns you need
            writer.writerow(shortened_row)
```

Whenever you find yourself writing `range(len(something))`, that's a good sign that you probably want to use `enumerate()`, which will loop through your data and automatically keep track of the current index.

For parsing each row after the header, you can use the slice notation `row[start:end]` and add slices together to get a new list, which you can then write to a file. Keep in mind that `row[start:end]` will **not** return the item at index `end`, which can be counter intuitive.

Finally, I always add `newline=''` when working with CSVs, since you can get unexpected line breaks otherwise, but this might be something `clevercsv` handles for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution! I definitely have some fundamentals I should work on, enumerate() will be a great help :)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, I would recommend using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org) for this sort of operation.

First isolate the CSV data. Then treat it as a stream. I am dropping part of your sample in as `x`:

```
# This is python3 code
# first treat string as though it is a file
import io
x = io.StringIO("""Symbol,Market,Description,Quantity,Average Cost,Price,Book Cost,Market Value,Unrealized $,Unrealized %,% of Positions,Loan Value,Change Today $,Change Today %,Bid,Bid Lots,Ask,Ask Lots,Volume,Day Low,Day High,52-wk Low,52-wk High
AFL,US,"AFLAC INC",500,43.79,39.23,21895.79,19615.00,-2280.79,-10.42,7.26,,1.4399986,3.81,39.19,1,40.2,1,3001288,38.31,39.48,23.07,57.18
AKTS,US,"AKOUSTIS TECHNOLOGIES INC",2500,5.04,8.94,12609.87,22350.00,9740.13,77.24,8.27,,0.35999966,4.20,8.68,1,9.2,10,1161566,8.65,9.25,3.76,9.25""")
```

Then use pandas to read the string as CSV, treating the first row as headers by default:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(x)
```

Then select the columns you want by passing a list of column names to the data frame:

```
new_df = df[['Book Cost', 'Market Value', 'Unrealized $', 'Unrealized %','% of Positions','52-wk Low', '52-wk High']]
```

```
   Book Cost  Market Value  Unrealized $  Unrealized %  % of Positions  \
0   21895.79       19615.0      -2280.79        -10.42            7.26   
1   12609.87       22350.0       9740.13         77.24            8.27   

   52-wk Low  52-wk High  
0      23.07       57.18  
1       3.76        9.25
```

Finally you can save it:

```
new_df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)  # Turn off indexing
```

And you are set:

```
Book Cost,Market Value,Unrealized $,Unrealized %,% of Positions,52-wk Low,52-wk High
21895.79,19615.0,-2280.79,-10.42,7.26,23.07,57.18
12609.87,22350.0,9740.13,77.24,8.27,3.76,9.25
```

Comment: Damn pandas are something I should really learn! Thanks a lot for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

(Full disclosure, I'm the author of CleverCSV.)

If you'd like to use CleverCSV for this task, and your data is small enough to fit into memory, you could use `clevercsv.read_csv` to load the data and `clevercsv.write_table` to save the data. By using these functions you don't have to worry about CSV dialects etc. You could also find the index of the header row automatically. It could go something like this:

```py
from clevercsv import read_csv, write_table

# Load the table with CleverCSV
table = read_csv(in_file_name)

# Find the index of the header row and get the header
header_idx = next((i for i, r in enumerate(table) if r[0] == 'Symbol'), None)
header = table[header_idx]

# Extract the data as a separate table
data = table[header_idx+1:]

# Create a list of header names that you want to keep
keep = ["Symbol", "Description", "Quantity","Average Cost","Price","Book Cost","Market Value","Unrealized $","Unrealized %","% of Positions","52-wk Low", "52-wk High"]

# Turn that list into column indices (and ensure all exist)
keep_idx = [header.index(k) for k in keep]

# Then create a new table by adding the header and the sliced rows
new_table = [keep]
for row in data:
  new_row = [row[i] for i in keep_idx]
  new_table.append(new_row)

# Finally, write the table to a new csv file
write_table(new_table, out_file_name)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, and thank you for creating an awesome library! I will be using it in the future :)